# Angular Mat Table Column Select and Deselect

Tags: angular, angular-material-6, mat-table

Please go through link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-table-order-resize-toggle?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html As per the link I need to do for Angular Mat table selecting and deselecting columns.

Comment: what is your issue?

Comment: Just create two arrays - one with all available columns, and one that will contain the columns you currently want to see. Use latter one with your mat-table, and create a function for adding/removing options from the first array to the second one. The Material Table will then hide/show the columns based on the content of the latter array.

Comment: Thanks for the response. as per the link in options am having column list based on column selection the table will update if columns are more user can customize the table.

Comment: @LarsRødal is there any possible to make one example in stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple proof of concept: https://stackblitz.com/edit/poc-column-selector
The table is hidden if no columns are selected, if you select one or more column they are displayed using the full width (flex).

The displayed order of the columns is decided by their order in the string-array with column definitions, not by the order of the markup in the html file.